# I am getting error "G-code error: Bad character '\357' used" on my tormach 440 after I import gcode, why is this happening?

Tags: cnc

I am getting "10:39:49 | **G-code error: Bad character '\357' used**" in my class's ***Tormach 440*** console when I import my code. Does anyone know any potential causes to this?

Edit: I don't know what '\357' means and I've already searched for anything that says \357 (there isn't) and I already made sure line 357 doesn't have a misspelling.

Edit 2: It isn't any weird Unicode character

Edit 3: Turns out the problem was that inside of a comment I had a < and a >

Comment: What does \357 mean? does it exist? what have you checked for?

Comment: could be an unexpected unicode character ... maybe this https://codepoints.net/U+0357 or https://codepoints.net/U+0165 ... decimal 357 = hexadecimal 165

Comment: So try to find the character causing the issue.

Comment: Two accounts? you should sort that.